# Using linear regression for prediction in python

Tags: python, linear-regression, prediction

I am a newbie in python.I am trying a simple prediction using linear regression.here is the dataset I am working:

```
    serial  Tt        Tv      Nc
    90     71675     425595  3171
    91     74865     441560  15965
```

Here is the code

```
#import library
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#dataset
data = pd.read_excel("testtv.xlsx")

#import linear regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#getting dependent variable and independent variable
x=data['Tt']
y=data['Tv']

#prediction
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.1)
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(np.array(x_train).reshape(-1,1),np.array(y_train).reshape(-1,1))
```

How can I print predicted value for next 7 'serial'?I have used the x values as 'Tt' and y values 'Tv'.Moreover, increasing test_size=0.8 gives wrong prediction value.How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you explain? next 7 serial? All you need is Tt value to predict Tv.

Comment: Is every serial denoting a sequence of day? If you dont have next 7 days x values then you could use x values with respect to timestamp.

Comment: yes serial represents as sequence of day.Can you explain more how to work with timestamp? Can I predict Tv using serial?